# Using iptables to redirect all traffic to local webserver

Tags: networking, iptables, router, dd-wrt

I'm trying to redirect all traffic on my wifi router to a local webserver using iptables. I'm not sure I have got the command right and also I want to exclude the router IP (172.16.0.1) from the rule to prevent myself from locking myself out from accessing the router.

What I've come up with so far:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 172.16.0.2:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 172.16.0.2:80
```

I tested above and it cause me not to be able to access the router again and the redirect is not working. What am I doing wrong, and how can exclude 172.16.0.1 from being redirected to 172.16.0.2?

Setup: 172.16.0.2 is the IP for the webserver 172.16.0.1 is my router (dd-wrt) no internet connection.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

- User connects to wifi hotspot, trying to access www.siteA.com, gets
  redirected to 172.16.0.2 (/index.html)
- User connects to wifi hotspot, trying to access www.siteB.com, gets redirected to 172.16.0.2
  (/index.html)
- User tries to access 172.16.0.1 and no direction takes place

Comment: You doing this iptables stuff in you wifi router?

Comment: If malyy's answer solved your (asked) problem, please indicate so with the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorr for forgetting to close the question! I ended up using the dnsmasq in the dd-wrt router, eg.

address=/thedomain.com/172.16.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is this single rule:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --src 0/0 --dst 172.16.0.2
```

This will insert into PREROUTING chain (?=-I) of the nat table (-t nat) the rule, that says:

Any incomming (-src 0/0) packets with destination address 172.16.0.2 (--dst 172.16.0.2).

Things to remember are:
To redirect incoming traffic means inserting rules into PREROUTING   chain of the nat table.   Redirection is done only for specified      interface.   More in man iptables, search for REDIRECT keyword.

```
--append PREROUTING  --source 172.16.0.1 --jump RETURN
```

RETURN means stop traversing this chain and resume at the next rule in the previous (calling) chain. If the end of a built-in chain is reached or a rule in a built-in chain with target RETURN is matched, the target specified by the chain policy determines the fate of the packet.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried this but have ran into some other issues which have lead me to the need of possibly creating a proxy / captive portal sollution instead as I will most likely run into problems with https -> http redirects, URI etc... But thanks for the reply!